# Pointer subtraction confusion

Tags: c, pointers

When subtracting two pointers from each other the difference represents the  number of elements between them (when pointing to int).

Why is the difference zero when pointing to type double?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     double data[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
     double  *iptr1;
     double *iptr2;
     double  val;
     iptr1 = &data[0];
     iptr2 = &data[9];
     val = iptr2 - iptr1;
     printf("Distance between the two addresses = %d\n", val);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't assign the difference of two pointers to a `double`, that's really strange. Use `ptrdiff_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing a `double` value with `%d`, which expects an integer. Change the type of `val` to `int` and everything will work as expected.

Note that, as suggested in the comments below, C defines a type for pointer differences, `ptrdiff_t`. This is guaranteed to *always* hold a value arising from a pointer difference, regardless of how far the actual pointers are. Although, if you are absolutely sure that the difference will fit an `int`, as in your question, that type should be fine as well. But `double` makes no sense at all, pointer differences cannot be fractional values.

Comment: Normally pptrdiff_t is used as type of pointer difference. http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4007211/Standard-C-s-pointer-difference-type

Comment: Right, going to fix my answer. But for a small difference such as the question's, int will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`Double` is not the correct type for pointer differences. Use `ptrdiff_t`, as defined in `stddef.h` instead.
[See here for the Data Types](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Important-Data-Types.html)

Instead of

```
printf("Distance between the two addresses = %d\n", val);
```

use then also

```
ptrdiff_t val = iptr2 - iptr1;
printf("Distance between the two addresses = %td\n", val);
```